# Take a User Specified list and search for all instance of text in a folder full of excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that takes user input for a folder containing excel files and then another input for a specified "key-word" or "Dirty-Word" search. I can not get it to pull every instance for the word search. It searches all files and is looking for the correct instances, but does not pull more than one hit. I have a test folder set with multiple simple excel 2013 workbooks containing a small amount of cells with some repeated text. The loops appear to be working correctly but how do I get it to display all matches and not just the first?

```
Sub WordSearch()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Testfolder As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim CheckReport As Variant
Dim CheckLength As Long
Dim Wordcheck As String
Dim Checksheet As Object

Set WS = Sheets.Add

' Open file folder for excel files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    Testfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'Open the target workbook
CheckReport = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls*", _
1, "Select Your CheckList File To Open", , False)

' Create Header and information for final sheet
WS.Range("A1") = "Path"
WS.Range("B1") = Testfolder
WS.Range("A2") = "CheckList:"
WS.Range("B2") = CheckReport
WS.Range("A4") = "Matched Word"
WS.Range("B4") = "Workbook"
WS.Range("C4") = "Worksheet"
WS.Range("D4") = "Cell Address"
WS.Range("E4") = "Link"

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Files = Dir(Testfolder)

'Set loop to search all files in the designated folder
Do Until Files = ""

    If Files = "." Or Files = ".." Then
    MsgBox "No Excel files found"

    Else
        If Right(Files, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Files, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Files, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Testfolder & Files, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                WS.Range("B5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Files
                WS.Range("C5").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Password protected"
                a = a + 1

                On Error GoTo 0
            Else

            ' Open the CheckSheet to let loop count and get search words
            Set Checksheet = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CheckReport).Worksheets("Sheet1")
            CheckLength = Checksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For Checkcell = 1 To CheckLength

                 Wordcheck = Checksheet.Cells(Checkcell, 1).Text

                    ' Set loop for each sheet in a workbook
                    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

                         ' Set loop for each cell on a worksheet
                         Set CellCheck = sheet.Cells.Find(Wordcheck, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                        If Not CellCheck Is Nothing Then
                            firstaddress = CellCheck.Address
                        End If

                            Do Until CellCheck Is Nothing

                                WS.Range("A5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Wordcheck
                                WS.Range("B5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Files
                                WS.Range("C5").Offset(a, 0).Value = sheet.Name
                                WS.Range("D5").Offset(a, 0).Value = CellCheck.Address
                                WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("E5").Offset(a, 0), Address:=Testfolder & Files, SubAddress:= _
                                sheet.Name & "!" & CellCheck.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"

                                a = a + 1

                                Set CellCheck = Range("A1:A10").FindNext(after:=CellCheck)

                               If CellCheck.Address = firstaddress Then
                                 Exit Do
                               End If

                            Loop 

                  Next sheet

             Next Checkcell

            Workbooks(Files).Close SaveChanges:=False

            End If

        End If

    Files = Dir

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

I modified the code to create a loop based on the activesheet count. Now it is giving multiple duplicate instances and not logging the correct cell.address.

```
Sub WordSearch()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Testfolder As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim CheckReport As Variant
Dim CheckLength As Long
Dim Wordcheck As String
Dim Checksheet As Object
Dim CellLoop As Long

Set WS = Sheets.Add

' Open file folder for excel files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    Testfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'Open the target workbook
CheckReport = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls*", _
1, "Select Your CheckList File To Open", , False)

' Create Header and information for final sheet
WS.Range("A1") = "Path"
WS.Range("B1") = Testfolder
WS.Range("A2") = "CheckList:"
WS.Range("B2") = CheckReport
WS.Range("A4") = "Matched Word"
WS.Range("B4") = "Workbook"
WS.Range("C4") = "Worksheet"
WS.Range("D4") = "Cell Address"
WS.Range("E4") = "Link"

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Files = Dir(Testfolder)

'Set loop to search all files in the designated folder
Do Until Files = ""

    If Files = "." Or Files = ".." Then
    MsgBox "No Excel files found"

    Else
        If Right(Files, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Files, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Files, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Testfolder & Files, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                WS.Range("B5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Files
                WS.Range("C5").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Password protected"
                a = a + 1

                On Error GoTo 0
            Else

            ' Open the CheckSheet to let loop count and get search words
            Set Checksheet = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CheckReport).Worksheets("Sheet1")
            CheckLength = Checksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            For Checkcell = 1 To CheckLength

                 Wordcheck = Checksheet.Cells(Checkcell, 1).Text

                    ' Set loop for each sheet in a workbook
                    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    SheetCheck = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

                    ' Set loop for each cell on a worksheet
                    For CellLoop = 1 To SheetCheck

                         Set CellCheck = sheet.Cells.Find(Wordcheck, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                        If Not CellCheck Is Nothing Then
                            firstaddress = CellCheck.Address

                            Do

                                WS.Range("A5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Wordcheck
                                WS.Range("B5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Files
                                WS.Range("C5").Offset(a, 0).Value = sheet.Name
                                WS.Range("D5").Offset(a, 0).Value = CellCheck.Address
                                WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("E5").Offset(a, 0), Address:=Testfolder & Files, SubAddress:= _
                                sheet.Name & "!" & CellCheck.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"

                                a = a + 1

                            Loop While Not CellCheck Is Nothing And CellCheck.Address <> firstaddress

                        End If

                        Next CellLoop

                    Next sheet

            Next Checkcell

            Workbooks(Files).Close SaveChanges:=False

            End If

        End If

    Files = Dir

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

After much trial and error...Here is the finished VBA Macro to take user inputs for folder location and search word criteria and generate another spreadsheet laying it all out.

```
Sub WordSearch()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Testfolder As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim CheckReport As Variant
Dim CheckLength As Long
Dim Wordcheck As String
Dim Checksheet As Object
Dim CellAddress As String

Set WS = Sheets.Add

MsgBox "Please select the Folder where the Excel files are located after you click OK."

' Open file folder for excel files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the Excel Folder Location"
    .Show
    Testfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

MsgBox "Please select the File that contains the Dirty Word list after. Click OK to continue."

'Open the target workbook
CheckReport = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls*", _
1, "Select Your Dirty Word List File To Open", , False)

' Create Header and information for final sheet
WS.Range("A1") = "Path"
WS.Range("B1") = Testfolder
WS.Range("A2") = "CheckList:"
WS.Range("B2") = CheckReport
WS.Range("A4") = "Matched Word"
WS.Range("B4") = "Workbook"
WS.Range("C4") = "Worksheet"
WS.Range("D4") = "Cell Address"
WS.Range("E4") = "Link"

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Files = Dir(Testfolder)

'Set loop to search all files in the designated folder
Do Until Files = ""

    If Files = "." Or Files = ".." Then
    MsgBox "No Excel files found"

    Else
        If Right(Files, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Files, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Files, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Testfolder & Files, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                WS.Range("B5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Files
                WS.Range("C5").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Password protected"
                a = a + 1

                On Error GoTo 0
            Else

            ' Open the CheckSheet to let loop count and get search words
            Set Checksheet = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CheckReport).Worksheets("Sheet1")
            CheckLength = Checksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            For Checkcell = 1 To CheckLength

                 Wordcheck = Checksheet.Cells(Checkcell, 1).Text

                    ' Activate Current Workbook
                      Workbooks(Files).Activate
                    ' Set loop for each sheet in a workbook
                    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

                    SheetCheck = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

                         Set CellCheck = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=Wordcheck, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                        If Not CellCheck Is Nothing Then
                            CellAddress = CellCheck.Address

                            Do

                                WS.Range("A5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Wordcheck
                                WS.Range("B5").Offset(a, 0).Value = Files
                                WS.Range("C5").Offset(a, 0).Value = sheet.Name
                                WS.Range("D5").Offset(a, 0).Value = CellCheck.Address
                                WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("E5").Offset(a, 0), Address:=Testfolder & Files, SubAddress:= _
                                sheet.Name & "!" & CellAddress, TextToDisplay:="Link"

                                a = a + 1

                                Set CellCheck = sheet.Cells.FindNext(After:=CellCheck)

                        Loop While Not CellCheck Is Nothing And CellCheck.Address <> CellAddress

                      End If

                    Next sheet

            Next Checkcell

            Workbooks(Files).Close SaveChanges:=False

            End If

        End If

    Files = Dir

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tired stepping through the code to see where the problem occurs?

Comment: I have tried stepping through the code and it was just jumping out. Now I have added a loop with the Sheet count to try to control it, but it is giving multiple instances of the same thing and logging an incorrect cell.address:

Comment: When you say jumping out, what do you mean? What is the last line that **successfully** runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Nothing like good old F8 to walk through each step and Google to give you options.